# Where can I find SQL Server 2014 Service Broker External Activator?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, service-broker

Can anyone point me towards the Service Broker External Activator for SQL Server 2014? I can't find any mention of it, only the EA for 2008 and 2012.

Comment: Disagree with close - This was not looking for an opinion or recommendation. This was trying to find a single, specific installation that oddly Google searches do not easily bring up.  The 2012 version pops up immediately, but the 2014 is not easily found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anybody needs it, it's here:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42295

Comment: Be aware that, `SSBEAS.msi` should be downloaded but the link above automatically downloads DB2OLEDBV5_x64.msi instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this MSDN link:

[**SQL Server Service Broker**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893(v=sql.120).aspx)

In particular, this section might be helpful:

**Where is the documentation for Service Broker?**

> The reference documentation for Service Broker is included in the SQL
>   Server 2014 documentation. This reference documentation includes the
>   following sections:
>
> 1. Data Definition Language (DDL) Statements (Transact-SQL) for CREATE,
>      ALTER, and DROP statements
> 2. Service Broker Statements
> 3. Service Broker Catalog Views (Transact-SQL)
> 4. Service Broker Related Dynamic Management Views (Transact-SQL)
> 5. ssbdiagnose Utility (Service Broker)
>
> See the previously published documentation for Service Broker concepts
>   and for development and management tasks. This documentation is not
>   reproduced in the SQL Server 2014 documentation due to the small
>   number of changes in Service Broker in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Thanks, I finally found it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42295 

Had to go to the second page in google. #firstworldproblems

Comment: Awesome! Seems like they wanted to hide it for some reason. :)